# What happens to the memory allocated in a function call like so?

Tags: c, memory, memory-leaks

I have a question about the following function and about memory allocation.

```
char    *strjoin(char const *s1, char const *s2)
{
    char    *s3;

    s3 = NULL;
    if (s1 && s2)
    {
        s3 = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(s1) + strlen(s2) + 1));
        if (!s3)
            return (NULL);
        strcpy(s3, s1);
        strcat(s3, s2);
    }
    return (s3);
}

int main()
{
    char    *s1 = "my favorite animal is";
    char    *s2 = " ";
    char    *s3 = "the nyancat";
    char    *res = strjoin(strjoin(s1, s2), s3);
}
```

The strjoins doc is as follows:

> Allocates (with malloc(3)) and returns a “fresh” string ending with
>   ’\0’, result of the concatenation of s1 and s2. If the allocation
>   fails the function returns NULL.

In the main function, the function calls itself on this line:

> char    *res = strjoin(strjoin(s1, s2), s3);

Since memory is being allocated in the strjoin(s1, s2) but never assigned to anything, and it is being used in the outer function call, but never freed technically, does that memory just leak and go unused?

Comment: You're assigning it to `res` there, and yes it would leak memory but no, in a 
*hosted* system the memory is freed when `main` exits.

Comment: And if you use an optimizing compiler, it will notice that all of this is nonsense and compile a simpler version: `int main(void) { return 0; }`.

Comment: ah, yes the inner function call *does* leak memory :_D

Comment: any practical tips to avoid such a thing?

Comment: @Thunderpurtz Thumbrule: Free any memory block right before you discard the last reference (i.e. pointer) to it.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala none of the compiler will optimize it as this program has a side effect. Your assumptions are wrong. Do avoid useless discusions here you have a ready example - please find the compiler which will optimize it just to the return. https://godbolt.org/z/Zesfr-

Comment: @P__J__ you're talking nonsense. There are no side effects. However you're correct that GCC/Clang are not clever enough to dig deep enough. See my answer for a simpler case.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala so please find me the "sense" compiler (one will be enough). Otherwise you talk nonsense.

Comment: @P__J__ it is [linked to in my answer](https://godbolt.org/z/QElKRA).

Comment: So yeah, I couldn't find an optimizing compiler that can track through a leaf and a branch call.

Comment: @P__J__ new one: https://godbolt.org/z/6qye_d

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the inner call does leak memory. You can avoid the leak easily by storing the return value in place:

```
char    *intermediate;
char    *res = strjoin(intermediate = strjoin(s1, s2), s3);
free(intermediate);
```

or

```
char    *intermediate = strjoin(s1, s2);
char    *res = strjoin(intermediate, s3);
free(intermediate);
```

But the memory would be freed by the operating system `main` function / when `exit` is called if this is a *hosted* system. Unless you're programming an embedded device, device driver or an operating system, you're very probably targetting a hosted platform.

---

Now, depending on whether the compiler is clever or not, it might not actually allocate *any* memory for that program, because the result is not needed.

Consider the slightly changed program:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

static inline __attribute__((always_inline)) char *strjoin(char const *s1, char const *s2)
{
    char    *s3; 
    s3 = NULL;

    if (s1 && s2) {
        s3 = malloc(strlen(s1) + strlen(s2) + 1);
        strcpy(s3, s1);
        strcat(s3, s2);
    }

    return s3;
}

int main()
{
    char    *s1 = "my favorite animal is";
    char    *s2 = " ";
    char    *s3 = "the nyancat";
    char    *res = strjoin(strjoin(s1, s2), s3);
}
```

**I've added `static inline __attribute__((always_inline))` to the function so that it is seen only within the *file scope* but not from other `.c` files (it doesn't have *external linkage*), and that the function will always be inlined in place; I've also removed the return value checking for *`malloc`*, as it seemed to hinder GCC's ability of deducing what will happen here.** (It somehow thinks that tracking the `NULL` status of `malloc` is relevant).

If you compile this program with highest optimization level with [latest GCC trunk](https://godbolt.org/z/6qye_d) the compiler will notice that all of the calculations are useless and compiles [a much simpler program](https://godbolt.org/z/ZZ5V3P):

```
int main(void) {
}
```

(see the identical assembly in the middle pane) that will have the [*same observable behaviour*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15718262/what-exactly-is-the-as-if-rule), but which does not call `malloc` even once.